# How can suppress Warning "Method can be void"?

Tags: android, suppress-warnings

Hi I am analyzing the code with the android studio tool, and a few methods have got the following warning "Method can be null", and I want to suppress this, but I don't find the quote to SupressWarnings.

Thanks.

Comment: @BobbyCarelse That is a completely different situation. Method can be void is a method returning an unused value. Constant conditions is that the variable passed to a method may be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press "Alt+Enter" on the method, on one of the suggestions (light bulbs), press right key, then select "Disable Inspection".

This should disable all null checks. Use carefully, though. If that's not what you require, select other options, all of them are listed there.

Comment: What about suppressing a single instance without disabling the check?